# Split a senctence into words and store them in linked list

Tags: c, string, matrix, linked-list, slice

I'm trying to write a program that gets a string, split it into words and then stores every single word in a linked list. The idea here is that every time the program reads a separator(space, comma, semicolon...) it appends the word into a matrix to store them into linked lists afterwards.
The problem here is that when it displays the matrix or linked list content, it display random characters at the end.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<string.h>

typedef struct Mot_De_La_Phrase {
    char Mon_mot[50];
    struct Mot_De_La_Phrase* Adresse_Mot_suivant;
}Mot;


Mot* Inserer_au_debut(Mot* les_mots_de_laphrase,char mot[]){
        // creer un nouvel element
    Mot* premier_mot = malloc(sizeof(Mot));
        // copier la chaine de caractere
    strcpy(premier_mot->Mon_mot, mot);
        // affecter le pointeur du suivant au debut de le liste principale
    premier_mot->Adresse_Mot_suivant=les_mots_de_laphrase;
        // retourner l'@ du 1er element
    return premier_mot;
}

Mot* Inserer_a_la_fin(Mot* les_mots_de_laphrase, char* mot){
        // si la liste chainee est vdie
    if(les_mots_de_laphrase == NULL){
        // cration de la liste / reservation de memoire pour le 1er element
    les_mots_de_laphrase=malloc(sizeof(Mot));
        // c'est le 1er et dernier element (donc le prochain element est NULL)
    les_mots_de_laphrase->Adresse_Mot_suivant=NULL;
        // copier le mot
    strcpy(les_mots_de_laphrase->Mon_mot,mot);
        // retourner l'addresse du 1er element
    return les_mots_de_laphrase;
}
        // si la liste chainee n'est pas vide affecter le 1er element a un pointeur temporaire
    Mot* dernier_mot=les_mots_de_laphrase;
        // tanque le pointeur suivant n'es pas NULL (tanqu'on est pas arrivé au dernier
    while(dernier_mot->Adresse_Mot_suivant!=NULL){
        // passer a l'element suivant
    dernier_mot=dernier_mot->Adresse_Mot_suivant;
    }
        // creer un nouvel element a la fin de la liste
    dernier_mot->Adresse_Mot_suivant=malloc(sizeof(Mot));
        // copier le mot
    strcpy(dernier_mot->Adresse_Mot_suivant->Mon_mot,mot);
        // c'est le 1er et dernier element (donc le prochain element est NULL)
    dernier_mot->Adresse_Mot_suivant->Adresse_Mot_suivant=NULL;
        // retourner l'addresse du 1er element
    return les_mots_de_laphrase;
}

void Afficher_Liste(Mot* les_mots_de_laphrase){
    if(les_mots_de_laphrase == NULL)
        printf("La Liste est vide.\n");
    else{
        Mot* tmp = les_mots_de_laphrase;
        while(tmp!=NULL)
            {
            printf("%s\n",tmp->Mon_mot);
            tmp = tmp->Adresse_Mot_suivant;
            }
        }
}


int separateur(char a){
    return(a == ' ' || a == ',' || a == ';' || a == '.' || a == '?' || a == '!' || a == '-');
}

int decoupage(char phrase[], char mots[][50]){
    int i,j,k;
    i=0;
    j=0;
    k=0;
    for(i=0;phrase[i]!='\0';i++){
        if(separateur(phrase[i])){
            mots[k][j] = '\0';
            k++;
            j=0;
            i++;
        }
        mots[k][j] = phrase[i];
        j++;
    }
    for(i=0;i<=k;i++)
        printf("%s\n",mots[i]);
    return k;
}

void main(){
    char phrase[100];
    char mots_phrase[50][50];
    Mot *mots = NULL;
    int i, n;
    gets(phrase);
    printf("%s\n",phrase);

    n = decoupage(phrase, mots_phrase);
    mots = Inserer_a_la_fin(mots, mots_phrase[0]);

    for(i=1;i<=n;i++)
        mots = Inserer_a_la_fin(mots, mots_phrase[i]);
    Afficher_Liste(mots);
}
```

I know it looks messy as hell. I'm just getting back to C after a while.
Also, I had to write keywords and comments in french because I have to send it to my college, sorry.

Comment: The loop in `decoupage` stops before appending the `'\0'` to the last word. Quick and dirty fix is `char mots_phrase[50][50] = {0};` But the real fix is to remove `mots_phrase` entirely. Each word in the phrase should be added directly to the linked list.

Comment: @HectorMarin Yes, that loop has a double-increment bug. But it works because after `i` is incremented inside the loop, the next character is saved as the first letter of the next word. There are a couple corner cases where that won't work, but if the input is clean, it works well enough.

Comment: @user3386109 That's right, but in the case that we have for example: "Yeah, that's correct", the space character after the comma character will pass as the first letter of the next word..

Comment: @HectorMarin Yup, that's exactly right. The code doesn't work correctly unless the phrase starts with the first letter of a word, has exactly one separator between words, and ends with the last letter of a word. Which is to say that OP needs to rethink how to handle the separators.